# call child elements inside parent on click from within parent

Tags: jquery, onclick, parent, toggleclass

How do i call a parent element onclick inside the parent?

For example, i have multiple of these on a page

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="some-text">text</div>
    <div class="some-image">image</div>
    <div class="some-btn">btn</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="some-text">text</div>
    <div class="some-image">image</div>
    <div class="some-btn">btn</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="some-text">text</div>
    <div class="some-image">image</div>
    <div class="some-btn">btn</div>
</div>
```

When i click the .some-btn i only whant it to happen for that .parent element, where the .some-btn is a child/clicked.

My jquery right now looks like this

```
$(".some-btn").click(function() {
    $(".some-text").toggleClass("active",1000,"easeInOutQuad");
    $(".some-image").toggleClass("active",1000,"easeInOutQuad");
    $(".some-btn").toggleClass("active");
})
```

But this of course activates all .parent elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the parent element of the clicked element and then select inside this element:

```
$(".some-btn").click(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    var par = that.closest('.parent');
    par.find(".some-text").toggleClass("active",1000,"easeInOutQuad");
    par.find(".some-image").toggleClass("active",1000,"easeInOutQuad");
    that.toggleClass("active");
})
```

Comment: Absolutely beautiful, that was exactly what i was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to traverse to closest parent div and then find elements in it:

```
$(".some-btn").click(function() {
  var _this = $(this);
  var closestparent = _this.closest('.parent')
  closestparent.find(".some-text,.some-image").toggleClass("active",1000,"easeInOutQuad");
 _this.toggleClass("active");
});
```

```js
 $(".some-btn").click(function() {
      var _this = $(this);
      var closestparent = _this.closest('.parent')
      closestparent.find(".some-text,.some-image").toggleClass("active",1000,"easeInOutQuad");
      _this.toggleClass("active");
    });
```

```css
.active{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="some-text">text</div>
    <div class="some-image">image</div>
    <div class="some-btn">btn</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="some-text">text</div>
    <div class="some-image">image</div>
    <div class="some-btn">btn</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="some-text">text</div>
    <div class="some-image">image</div>
    <div class="some-btn">btn</div>
</div>
```